# Android Studio SDL2 Invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size

Tags: android, c++, linux, android-studio, sdl-2

I am having problems compiling SDL2 for android. I have gotten to a point where the NDK is throwing an error about a header included by SDL.h.

mmintrin.h is the header included with the ndk that is problematic.

Invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size

SDL.h

```
#include "SDL_cpuinfo.h"
```

SDL_cpuinfo.h

```
#if !defined(_MSC_VER) || __has_feature(modules) || defined(__MMX__)
#include <mmintrin.h>
#endif
```

mmintirin.h

```
static __inline__ __m64 __DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS
_mm_cvtsi32_si64(int __i)
{
    return (__m64)__builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si(__i, 0);
}
```

This is all stock code from the SDL project and a fresh install of android studio.

```
    In file included from /home/nick/development/extenal_git/SDL/include/SDL.h:38:
In file included from /home/nick/development/extenal_git/SDL/include/SDL_cpuinfo.h:102:
In file included from /home/nick/Android/Sdk/ndk/16.1.4479499/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/5.0.300080/include/immintrin.h:28:
/home/nick/Android/Sdk/ndk/16.1.4479499/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib64/clang/5.0.300080/include/mmintrin.h:64:12: error: invalid conversion between vector type '__m64' (vector of 1 'long long' value) and integer type 'int' of different size
```

Comment: @drescherjm I have added what code is erroring out. It is sparce. I understand the exception but not how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I started from scratch and did not encounter this issue again. May have been misconfiguration of the .mk files.